# 1.9 summoning in a spawn egg item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am in 1.9 and I need to summon in a squid egg with certain properties

For example this needs to be called "Barbed Wire"

I have tried this command

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:spawn_egg,Count=1b},ench:[],display:{Name:"Barbed Wire"},EntityTag:{id:"Squid",CustomName:"Barbed Wire",Tags:["BW"]}}
```

However when i power this is does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Tag names and values are separated by colons, not equal signs (should be `Count:1b`). Any item data that is not `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, or `Slot`, must be placed within a single `tag` tag. You've placed all of the extra item data outside of the item specification and at the root of the item entity.

Fixed command:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:spawn_egg,Count:1b,tag:{ench:[],display:{Name:"Barbed Wire"},EntityTag:{id:"Squid",CustomName:"Barbed Wire",Tags:["BW"]}}}}
```